# Jax WS caching on client side

Tags: web-services, jsf, jsf-2, jax-ws

I have an JSF 2.0 web application which requests external Jax-WS and reders result applying business logic on it.

Is there any way to cache result from from WS and render result from cache instead of consuming it each time? which framework is most useful for it?